# Measure impact of new software on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance, perfmon, resources, metrics

I'm an admin for a small business. I've been asked to give another company my opinion on whether or not our servers have enough available resources to handle the addition of their software. I've had minimal experience with PerfMon so I'm not quite sure what to measure that would be most useful.

I need to assess two Win2k3 terminal servers with a load of about 40 people daily. The new software package would be front end GUI to a database on another server and we should assume that nearly ever person on the server will access the software. I'm sure I should be looking into how much "resource" is available in processor, memory, and network throughput but I'm not sure what metrics I should specifically look at.

Does anyone have any tips for me?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a good run down on this complicated subject http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771692(v=ws.10).aspx

Use that against what the software vendor says you willl for your servers and keep track afterwards as weell for what it actually uses.